# Typescript type check in function called after conditional check

Tags: typescript

I wasn't sure how to word the question correctly, but here's my setup:

```
const params = getParams()

if (params) {
  checkParams()
}


function getParams(): {param1: string, param2: string} | null {
    ...
}

function checkParams() {
    const {param1, param2} = params
    ...
}
```

The code in the sample is representative, i.e. the sequence, scope, etc. Meaning `params` is accessible to the `checkParams()` function. The issue that I am facing is that I get an error from TypeScript on `params` in my `checkParams()` function:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
```

Why is that? `checkParams()` is only ever called when `params` is **not** `null`.

Comment: Typescript can not know if that's the only way the function will be called.

Comment: If you make sure that `params` is always not null, add a `if (!params) { return;}` at the beginning of the `checkParams()` method? As @ritaj said, Typescript cannot know that otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript can not know if that's the only way the function will be called.

You can use a non-null assertion operator to tell Typescript that the object will indeed be defined:

```
function checkParams() {
    const {param1, param2} = params!;
}
```

Comment: What I've done is I passed `params` as an argument, i.e. `checkParams(params)`, and set a type on function definition, i.e. `function checkParams(params: {...})`, which satisfied TypeScript. But overall your explanation seems credible.